# Refresh the page when the 'OK' alert button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an alert script that shows to users who don't have an underscore between the numbers they wrote in the input of the form (e.g 888_1132).

Since I can't remove the 'OK' button from the alert, I want the page to be refreshed when the 'OK' button is clicked.

```
function myFunction()
{
    alert("Click 'OK' to refresh this page");
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mM3Rj/)

Can I do that with the alert button? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code in your question, not just on jsFiddle.

Comment: It's not showing on the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the script will block until the OK is pressed, then simply add `location.reload();` below the alert

```
function myFunction()
{
    alert("Click 'OK' and the page will be refreshed");
    location.reload();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
window.location.reload(true);
```

Add that RIGHT after your `alert()`

Including `true` will ensure the page is fully reloaded from the server and not from local cache.  If you want to use cache, leave blank or use `false`